# How can I add one to the greater of two values in Excel?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I have MS Excel 2013 installed on my computer, running Windows 7.

In Excel, I have a spreadsheet, in which I have two cells, each with a value determined by a formula.

How can I add 1 to the largest value of the two cells?

Comment: Please [edit] the question title so that is describes your issue **not** what you are using. What you are using belongs in the question body and the tags.

Comment: Excel 2011 is a OSX version. Please double check which version you are using, [edit] and add the appropriate tag

Comment: Are you looking to add 1 to the largest of the two values? If so, what do you want to do with this number?

Comment: Yes I am looking to add 1 to the largest of the 2 values, thanks

Comment: Are you looking to increase the value of the largest one "in place" (change the value of that actual cell), or produce a result in another cell equal to the largest value +1?

Comment: I am needing to change the value of the actual cell in place by 1

Comment: What you're trying to do is contrary to how Excel is designed to work.  You say the cells' values are determined by formulas.  A cell can't contain both a formula and a value, so to do what you want would require revising the formula in the larger cell on command, or replacing the formula with a value that is 1 larger than its current result, in which case you would no longer have the formula.  These could be done with VBA, but you would need to define a "trigger", because you would want this to happen once and only once so you don't have an endless loop of revision.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the IF function.

**If you want to set a cell to the value of the largest of the two cells + 1 and for it to automatically update when you change the values in the two cells:**

1. Create a new Excel document
2. Set up your two values in two cells
3. In another cell, write the formula `=IF(E1>E2, E1+1, E2+1)`, replacing E1 and E2 with the location of the cells your numbers are in.

[image: Formula Screenshot]

4. Press Return on your keyboard.

[image: Result Screenshot]

You can now change the two values and the cell will update with the largest value of the two + 1.

This uses an IF function that checks whether the value in Cell 1 is bigger than the value in Cell 2. If it is, then it adds 1 to the value of Cell 1 and displays it in the cell the function is in. If it is not, then it adds 1 to the value of Cell 2 and displays that instead.

Comment: @Rayne Hope this helps. If this isn't what you're looking for, please say!

Comment: thanks very much for replying, but I need it to add 1 to the larger of the 2 cells in place not in a third cell. would love it if you could nut this through.

Comment: Is the answer from @Lex more relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Large" function, and can expand on it if you need to include more than 2 cells in the future

Formular 
LARGE(array, k)
The LARGE function syntax has the following arguments:
    Array    Required. The array or range of data for which you want to determine the k-th largest value.
    K    Required. The position (from the largest) in the array or cell range of data to return.
=LARGE(A2:B6,3)
You can find more information [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LARGE-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

If you have your two cells/Column on A & B
Your first 2 rows of Column C would look like
=LARGE(A1:B1,1)+1
=LARGE(A2:B2,1)+1